# JQuery - Auto Refresh (Duplicating Forms)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this script for updating my div every x second.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('chatbox').load('chat.php').fadein('slow')
    }, 1000); // refresh every 1000 milliseconds
</script>
```

I used it to update the div of chat,But, When I viewed my page, It duplicated my whole page and showed it at the end of page, Nothing was working, The submission form and div were duplicated and Computer Usage went to 99%.

Anything wrong in that?

Comment: if your form is a div id than you should be using `$('#form')`.  And doing it every second is pretty hard on the cpu probably.

Comment: Are you sure you have exactly one `<form>` in your page ? And none in chat.php ?

Comment: Also, what page are you calling this from?  If you're calling it from chat.php, you're going to get the whole page again as it doesn't look like you're defining any way to say "hey, just load a portion of this chat.php page."

Comment: @jeschafe Yeah, I am calling the chat.php on chat.php, You got my problem correct, What should I do ?

Comment: @jeschafe I want to refresh a div where user comments are showing in group chat area, That div contains some php to show comments, It needs to be updated every 3 to 4 seconds to get the latest comments by other members just like a shoutbox. But, When I used the above code it just duplicated the whole page, I am calling on chat.php where all the functions are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "form" is a div id, it needs to be `$('#form')` not `$('form')`. The latter will load chat.php into every form element on the page.

Also, be sure that chat.php is ONLY printing the form element you need, and not the entire page. jQuery offers functionality to parse just what you need, `$('#form').load('form.php #form');`.

Keep in mind that the server is still sending the entire page to the client which is inefficient. If this is your issue, consider modifying your php to send just JSON (or similar) data, and format it as you need client side.

Comment: Good, Now the div is not updating and new comments are not showing :(

Comment: I want to update div so new comments by other users are also shown, Just like group chat area. But they are duplicated and refresh or donot work..

Comment: ".load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data". This means that any content in `#form` will be _replaced_ with whatever chat.php displays. If there are duplicates, make sure chat.php is **not** printing a NEW `#form` div, which would become a CHILD of the original `#form` div?

Comment: Exactly the same thing is happening, It is duplicating the whole page, Also the div wasn't updating and not showing the latest comments by others, Any solution of that?

Comment: As @jeschafe said above, you need to define WHAT you want to be refreshed. If you want JUST #form to be updated, consider appending a post variable to your ajax, (eg ?displayOnlyForm=true) and in chat.php, printing ONLY the contents of #form if displayOnlyForm is set.

Comment: ...actually, it looks like jQuery thought of that already: try `$('#form').load('form.php #form')`;